# ASP.Net user controls in a child directory, directory not found error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, build, .net-3.5

I've recently reorganised a web app so that instead of all the files sitting in the application root, everything is split into business area sub-folders and beneath that divided into folders by type.  So instead of having:

- ~/MasterPage.master
- ~/Page.aspx
- ~/UserControl.ascx

The structure is now like this:

- ~/App/Common/MasterPages/MasterPage.master
- ~/App/Common/Pages/Page.aspx
- ~/App/Common/UserControls/UserControl.ascx

This all works quite well on my machine, everything compiles and runs in Debug or Release mode, however when I deploy to the testing server things go a bit pear shaped.  To deploy I create an MSI using `_deploy` and `_msi` projects in visual studio, then run the MSI on the test server.

User controls that are referenced directly from an `.aspx` seem to be OK, but if a User Control has a child user control then errors ensue:

> Directory
>   'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp\App\Common\MasterPages'
>   does not exist. Failed to start
>   monitoring file changes.
>
> Directory
>   'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp\App\Common\UserControls'
>   does not exist. Failed to start
>   monitoring file changes.

The directories do not exist on the testing server because there's no files to go in them, all their contents are compiled into DLLs during the build, so the MSI doesn't have any files to copy into them.  If I create the directories by hand then everything starts working even though they're empty, so one obvious fix is to include a `blank.html` or similar in each folder so that they get created by the installer; another would be to put the user controls in the same directory with the pages -  but that all seems like papering over the real issue: why does the deployed web app needs these directories to exist in the first place?

So there are a few questions I'd like answers to:

- Is this a fundamentally wrong headed approach, can I expect to see further similar issues in the future because of this directory structure in the project? (And if so, what is a better way to organise the app?)
- Is there a way to configure the build so that ASP.net does not need to 'start monitoring file changes'?  (Is it something to do with the 'make compiled website updatable option?)
- Is there some good documentation of how all this works somewhere that explains what this issue is?

Comment: What version ASP.NET and it is a Web App project, correct?

Comment: @IrishChieftain .Net 3.5SP1 and how do I tell?  I have options like 'Build Web Site' if I right click on it.

Comment: I blogged about this way back: http://bit.ly/lUeISF ...copy over the user controls first and see if that works. If that fails and this is a website project, there are known issues with referencing user controls... better to convert to a Web App project instead if that's the case.

Comment: @IrishCheiftain It already works if I just create those directories on the server, what difference are you expecting it to make if I also copy the user controls over?

Comment: I think you need to include the .acsx files in your deployment....

Comment: @IrishCheiftain But I don't - it works already without the `.ascx` files being deployed, just by creating on the server the directory where the `.ascx` files are in the project.

Comment: Weird, all I know is that user controls are "Deployed in the source form (.ascx) along with the source code of the application": http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667 (check differences table at end of page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same exact error although any UserControl would cause it, regardless of whether it was used by a Page or another UserControl. I believe it only happened if that control was used more than 5 times in a single request.

**One workaround** is to add an empty Placeholder file to every directory containing a CustomControl and set the Placeholder file's properties to `Build Action: Content`, `Copy to Output Directory: Copy always`. That keeps the directories from disappearing when the site is published.